# Calculate and update DB field on entry creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Items controller with num1 num2 and sum field. I want to update the sum field in the database at the time of entry creation. I am placing this line in the items controller in the **create** function and I am successfully able to update the sum field in the DB.

```
@item.sum = @item.num1 + @item.num2
```

Is this the right approach?

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

def create
  @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
  @item.sum = @item.num1 + @item.num2 #Correct way ?
  if @item.save
    flash[:success] = "Item created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'static_pages/spage1'
  end
end

def destroy
end


private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:num1, :num2, :name)
  end

end
```

Comment: If controller is the only place where the `sum` should be updated, it is ok. But if this sum must be updated after each update of `num1` and `num2` attributes better way is to use `before_save` callback or... why do not use a model method which returns this sum?

Comment: You can also leave it as is and do it on the fly when reading/echo'ing the information.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Callback is the better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use this as well. But you should use [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).Your `item.rb` would look something like the following

```
before_create :set_sum_value

private
   def set_sum_value
      self.sum = (self.num1 + self.num2)
      true
   end
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot for introducing me to callbacks. Can you tell me why did you use 'true' in the method ?

Comment: it's a good practice to `return true` in callbacks..When we are setting some variables.. and if a value is false..it will return false otherwise..and it will not save your object

Comment: Point noted Amit. Thanks!